High CPU usage after using WITH CTE
I've updated the following query:
explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) 
SELECT
"works".id,
"works".err,
"works".duration,
"works".ts,
"works".ts_mod,
count(*) OVER() AS _count
FROM "works"
WHERE key = 'deb7908b-0e5b-11ed-940a-2b09f4934f0e' AND rel IN ('rel1', 'rel2')
ORDER BY "ts" DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;

to:
explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) with _total_count as (
  select count(*) as total 
  from "works"
  WHERE key = 'deb7908b-0e5b-11ed-940a-2b09f4934f0e' AND rel IN ('rel1', 'rel2')
) SELECT 
"works".id,
"works".err,
"works".duration,
"works".ts,
"works".ts_mod,
_total_count.total as _count
FROM "works", _total_count 
WHERE key = 'deb7908b-0e5b-11ed-940a-2b09f4934f0e' AND rel IN ('rel1', 'rel2') ORDER BY "ts" DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;


Reason for the change: I'm assuming that limit 20 was applied after all the rows were fetched making the query slow.
The new query is faster but now PG seems to be consuming more CPU, all the CPUs are being used by PG process and the load average is very high. Here's the output of explain analyze
Limit  (cost=26015.77..26098.03 rows=20 width=373) (actual time=6006.111..6006.221 rows=20 loops=1)
   Output: works.id, works.err, works.duration, works.ts, works.ts_mod, (count(*))
   Buffers: shared hit=2927 read=5084
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=26015.77..185905.90 rows=38875 width=373) (actual time=6006.109..6006.212 rows=20 loops=1)
         Output: works.id, works.err, works.duration, works.ts, works.ts_mod, (count(*))
         Buffers: shared hit=2927 read=5084
         ->  Index Scan using works_key_ts_idx on public.works  (cost=0.56..159404.74 rows=38875 width=365) (actual time=5.528..5.581 rows=20 loops=1)
               Output: works.id, works.rel, works.key, works.err, works.data, works.duration, works.ts_mod, works.ts, works.worker
               Index Cond: (works.key = 'deb7908b-0e5b-11ed-940a-2b09f4934f0e'::uuid)
               Filter: ((works.rel)::text = ANY ('{rel1,rel2}'::text[]))
               Buffers: shared hit=19 read=5
         ->  Materialize  (cost=26015.20..26015.23 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=300.030..300.030 rows=1 loops=20)
               Output: (count(*))
               Buffers: shared hit=2908 read=5079
               ->  Aggregate  (cost=26015.20..26015.21 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6000.548..6000.550 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Output: count(*)
                     Buffers: shared hit=2908 read=5079
                     ->  Index Only Scan using works_key_ts_rel_idx on public.works works_1  (cost=0.56..25918.02 rows=38875 width=0) (actual time=6.870..5983.970 rows=42842 loops=1)
                           Output: works_1.key, works_1.rel, works_1.ts
                           Index Cond: ((works_1.key = 'deb7908b-0e5b-11ed-940a-2b09f4934f0e'::uuid) AND (works_1.rel = ANY ('{rel1,rel2}'::text[])))
                           Heap Fetches: 4665
                           Buffers: shared hit=2908 read=5079
 Query Identifier: 2776669242247688065
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=241 read=65
 Planning Time: 56.642 ms
 Execution Time: 6007.031 ms
(27 rows)

Output of explain analyze for the 1st query:
 Limit  (cost=0.56..82.83 rows=20 width=373) (actual time=54796.241..54796.260 rows=20 loops=1)
   Output: id, err, duration, ts, ts_mod, (count(*) OVER (?))
   Buffers: shared hit=40 read=43211
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.56..159890.64 rows=38872 width=373) (actual time=54796.239..54796.253 rows=20 loops=1)
         Output: id, err, duration, ts, ts_mod, count(*) OVER (?)
         Buffers: shared hit=40 read=43211
         ->  Index Scan using works_key_ts_idx on public.works  (cost=0.56..159404.74 rows=38872 width=365) (actual time=6.291..54512.434 rows=42842 loops=1)
               Output: id, err, duration, ts, ts_mod
               Index Cond: (works.key = 'deb7908b-0e5b-11ed-940a-2b09f4934f0e'::uuid)
               Filter: ((works.rel)::text = ANY ('{rel1,rel2}'::text[]))
               Buffers: shared hit=40 read=43211
 Query Identifier: -3039821289787922465
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=226 read=56
 Planning Time: 44.856 ms
 Execution Time: 54797.983 ms
(16 rows)

Executing the query for the count with the where clause takes 5.8 seconds:
 Aggregate  (cost=26011.13..26011.14 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5848.115..5848.117 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=2907 read=5080
   ->  Index Only Scan using works_key_ts_rel_idx on public.works  (cost=0.56..25913.95 rows=38872 width=0) (actual time=7.295..5829.620 rows=42842 loops=1)
         Output: key, rel, ts
         Index Cond: ((works.key = 'deb7908b-0e5b-11ed-940a-2b09f4934f0e'::uuid) AND (works.rel = ANY ('{rel1,rel2}'::text[])))
         Heap Fetches: 4665
         Buffers: shared hit=2907 read=5080
 Query Identifier: -7766391099171370600
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=183 read=59
 Planning Time: 40.537 ms
 Execution Time: 5848.865 ms
(13 rows)

The time taken by the count query is roughly similar to the time taken by the 2nd query. I can excute two queries, one for count and another for the data but I wanted to know the reason behing the high CPU usage.
Here's the works Table schema:
brwsr=# \d+ works;
                                                            Table "public.works"
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |       Default        | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id          | uuid                     |           | not null | uuid_generate_v1mc() | plain    |             |              | 
 rel         | character varying(50)    |           | not null |                      | extended |             |              | 
 key         | uuid                     |           | not null |                      | plain    |             |              | 
 err         | text                     |           |          |                      | extended |             |              | 
 data        | text                     |           |          |                      | extended |             |              | 
 duration    | smallint                 |           |          |                      | plain    |             |              | 
 ts_mod      | timestamp with time zone |           |          | now()                | plain    |             |              | 
 ts          | timestamp with time zone |           |          | now()                | plain    |             |              | 
 worker      | text                     |           |          |                      | extended |             |              | 

Indexes:
    "works_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "works_key_ts_rel_idx" btree (key, rel, ts DESC)
    "works_ts_index" btree (ts DESC)
Access method: heap

Thanks for the help.

Your real problem is IO: It takes almost 5 seconds to get 42842 rows from an index.  That's imho very very slow. Any idea why your system is so slow? (by the way, your CPU might be busy waiting to get data from disk)

Why shouldn't the CPU usage be high?  It uses as much CPU as it needs to get the job done, and once there is no disk access delay it uses this CPU as fast as it can go.  What should it do instead?  Your plan doesn't show any use of parallel workers, so if it is using all the CPUs it must be because you have multiple different instances of the query running.
